# Adding a timer to surfaceview for control the game end

Tags: android, countdowntimer

How can i create a textPaint as a count down timer to control the game end?
I have tried to use countDownTimer with drawText to do something like that,it can show in surfaceview but it doesn't update for each onTick.

```
public class CfView extends SurfaceView {
/** The activity object. */
private final Activity activity;
/** The answer object. */
private static Answer answer;
private static int score;
/** The InputPanel object. */
private static InputPanel inputPanel;
/** The AnswerPanel object. */
private static AnswerPanel answerPanel;
/** Keyboard panel height. */
private static final float INPUT_PANEL_HEIGHT_WEIGHT = 0.7f;
/** Answer panel height. */
private static final float ANSWER_PANEL_HEIGHT_WEIGHT = 0.3f;
private Timer timer;
private String countDownTime;

private boolean gameOver;

private UserInput userInput = new UserInput();
private CountDownTimer cdTimer;

/** Saving and handling of user input of touch events. */
private class UserInput {
    /** Whether there is a user input present. */
    boolean present = false;
    /** Action of the user input {@link MotionEvent}. */
    int action;
    /** x, y positions of the user input {@link MotionEvent}. */
    int x, y;

    synchronized void save(MotionEvent event) {
        present = true;
        action = event.getAction();
        x = (int) event.getX();
        y = (int) event.getY();
        handle();
    }

    synchronized void handle() {
        int pos = -1;
        if (present) {
            cdTimer.start();
            if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                int[] clickedBallData = inputPanel.checkballStroked(x, y);
                if (clickedBallData != null) {
                    pos = clickedBallData[0];
                    int value = clickedBallData[1];
                    if (answer.isCorrect(value)) {
                        if (answer.isHCF(value)) {
                            score += 500;
                        } else {
                            score += 100;
                        }
                    } else {
                        score -= 100;
                        if (score < 0)
                            score = 0;
                    }
                    inputPanel.updateInputPanel(pos, answer);
                }
            }
            drawGameComponent();
            present = false;
        }
    }
}

private class AnimationTask extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("thread", "run");
        userInput.handle();
        Canvas canvas = getHolder().lockCanvas();
        if (canvas != null) {
            answerPanel.drawOn(canvas);
            inputPanel.drawOn(canvas);
            Paint textPaint = new Paint();
            textPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            textPaint.setTextSize(50);
            textPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
            canvas.drawText("Score : " + score, getWidth() * 0.7f, 50,
                    textPaint);
            textPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            textPaint.setTextSize(50);
            textPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
            canvas.drawText("Time : " + countDownTime + "s", 0, 50,
                    textPaint);
            if (gameOver) {
                textPaint.setTextSize(2 * 30);
                textPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
                canvas.drawText("Times up", getWidth() / 2,
                        getHeight() / 2, textPaint);
                canvas.drawText("Score : " + score, getWidth() / 2,
                        getHeight() / 2 + (2 * 30), textPaint);

            }
            getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }

    }

}

public CfView(Activity activity) {
    super(activity);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true); // For getting key events
    cdTimer = new CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            countDownTime = String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            invalidate();
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            countDownTime = 0 + "";
            gameOver = true;
            cancel();
        }
    };

    setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            userInput.save(event);

            return true;
        }
    });

    this.activity = activity;

    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new AnimationTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (getWidth() == 0)
                ; // Wait for layout
            newGame(true);


        }
    }, 0);

}

public void resume() {
    if (timer == null)
        timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new AnimationTask(), 0, 0);

}

public void pause() {
    timer.cancel();
    timer = null;
}

private void drawGameComponent() {
    Canvas canvas = getHolder().lockCanvas();
    if (canvas != null) {
        answerPanel.drawOn(canvas);
        inputPanel.drawOn(canvas);
        Paint textPaint = new Paint();
        textPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        textPaint.setTextSize(50);
        textPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        canvas.drawText("Score : " + score, getWidth() * 0.7f, 50,
                textPaint);
        getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }
}

public void drawTimeText() {
    Canvas canvas = getHolder().lockCanvas();
    Paint textPaint = new Paint();
    if (canvas != null) {
        textPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        textPaint.setTextSize(50);
        textPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
        canvas.drawText("Time : " + countDownTime + "s", 0, 50, textPaint);
        if (gameOver) {
            textPaint.setTextSize(2 * 30);
            textPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
            canvas.drawText("Times up", getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2,
                    textPaint);
            canvas.drawText("Score : " + score, getWidth() / 2, getHeight()
                    / 2 + (2 * 30), textPaint);

        }
        getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }

}

public void newGame(boolean newGame) {
    score = 0;
    gameOver = false;
    if (newGame) {
        answer = new Answer(activity);
        Log.d("CF", getHeight() + ";" + getWidth());
        answerPanel = new AnswerPanel(activity, 0, 0, getWidth(),
                (int) (getHeight() * ANSWER_PANEL_HEIGHT_WEIGHT), answer);
        inputPanel = new InputPanel(activity, 0,
                (int) (getHeight() * (ANSWER_PANEL_HEIGHT_WEIGHT)),
                getWidth(), (int) (getHeight()), answer);

    } else {
        answer.newNumber();
        inputPanel.resetInputPanel();
        answerPanel.resetAnswerPanel(answer);

    }
    drawGameComponent();
}

public void updateCategory(Answer.Level level) {
    answer.updateCategory(level);
    newGame(false);
}

@Override
protected boolean verifyDrawable(Drawable who) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public void invalidateDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
}
```

}

Comment: Can you edit your post to include your code? It's difficult to diagnose the issue without it.

Comment: i have posted the code